# MongoDB Query for documents in array .NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

With a MongoDB collection structure as in this example:

```json
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "memberinfo" : [{
        "height": 170,
        "weight": 55,
        "status": "approved",
        "fruits" : [ {"name" : "apple","reason" : null },
                     {"name" : "orange","reason" : null},
                     {"name" : "berry","reason" : null}
        ],
    }]
},
{
    "_id" : "456",
    "memberinfo" : [{
        "height" : 160,
        "weight": 90,
        "status": "approved",
        "fruits" : [ {"name" : "berry","reason" : null},
                     {"name" : "orange","reason" : null}
        ],
    },{
        "height" : 160,
        "weight": 90,
        "status": "rejected",
        "fruits" : [ {"name" : "banana","reason" : null}
        ],
    }]
}
```

How is it possible to query the nested array to get the `memberinfo` which has the `status:approved`.

The result should be like this:

```json
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "memberinfo" : [{
        "height": 170,
        "weight": 55,
        "status": "approved",
        "fruits" : [ {"name" : "apple","reason" : null },
                     {"name" : "orange","reason" : null},
                     {"name" : "berry","reason" : null}
        ],
    }]
},
{
    "_id" : "456",
    "memberinfo" : [{
        "height" : 160,
        "weight": 90,
        "status": "approved",
        "fruits" : [ {"name" : "berry","reason" : null},
                     {"name" : "orange","reason" : null}
        ],
    }]
}
```

I tried this but the result is not right:

```
IMongoQuery query = Query.And(Query.EQ("memberinfo.status", "approved"));
MongoCursor mongocursor = nsdb.GetCollection(DBPrefix, "Member").Find(query);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Projecting only matched sub-documents along with original document fields mongodb C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888703/projecting-only-matched-sub-documents-along-with-original-document-fields-mongod)

Comment: @Veeram saw your answer in that post, but i not understand why using so many `BsonDocument`

Comment: `BsonDocument` is  equivalent for `key value` pair. Example `{"key":"value"}` in C#  written as `new BsonDocument {
    {
        "key",
        "value"
    } }`

Comment: @Veeram thanks, but what u show to me , is not im looking for

Comment: Np. What are you looking for ? What driver version do you use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is quite straightforward; you need to specify a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) using the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) to make sure your query only returns the array items which matched the finding query:

```js
db.Member.find(
  { "memberinfo.status" : "approved" },
  {
    "_id" : 1, 
    "memberinfo.$" : 1
  }
);
```

Note: this is the native MongoDB version of the query; I'm not familiar with how this should be generated with the C# driver I'm afraid.

---

C# Update - Elemmatch version ( Works same as positional operator ) *[credit to Veerlam]*.

This solution works when you only have one `approved` status element in each `memberinfo` array.

```cs
IMongoFields fields = Fields.Include("_id").ElemMatch("memberinfo", Query.EQ("status", "approved"));
MongoCursor mongocursor = nsdb.GetCollection(DBPrefix, "Member").Find((Query.Empty).SetFields(fields);
```

Answer (score -1):

A solution using projection and positional operator is provided by Vince.

An alternate solution using [aggregration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) pipeline together with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) is given below

$unwind - this is used to break down the array elements into separate documents

Let us have the collection with the documents

```
db.collection.find()

    {
    "_id" : "123",
    "memberinfo" : [{
        "height": 170,
        "weight": 55,
        "status": "approved",
        "fruits" : [ {"name" : "apple","reason" : null },
                     {"name" : "orange","reason" : null},
                     {"name" : "berry","reason" : null}
        ],
    }]
},
{
    "_id" : "456",
    "memberinfo" : [{
        "height" : 160,
        "weight": 90,
        "status": "approved",
        "fruits" : [ {"name" : "berry","reason" : null},
                     {"name" : "orange","reason" : null}
        ],
    },{
        "height" : 160,
        "weight": 90,
        "status": "rejected",
        "fruits" : [ {"name" : "banana","reason" : null}
        ],
    }]
}
```

After using [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$memberinfo"}])

{
        "_id" : "123",
        "memberinfo" : {
                "height" : 170,
                "weight" : 55,
                "status" : "approved",
                "fruits" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "apple",
                                "reason" : null
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "orange",
                                "reason" : null
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "berry",
                                "reason" : null
                        }
                ]
        }
}
{
        "_id" : "456",
        "memberinfo" : {
                "height" : 160,
                "weight" : 90,
                "status" : "approved",
                "fruits" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "berry",
                                "reason" : null
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "orange",
                                "reason" : null
                        }
                ]
        }
}
{
        "_id" : "456",
        "memberinfo" : {
                "height" : 160,
                "weight" : 90,
                "status" : "rejected",
                "fruits" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "banana",
                                "reason" : null
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Now we have successfully unwinded the memberinfo array so that each document will have only one `memberinfo.status`

Now use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) in the aggregation pipeline to get the desired result

> Final Mongo Shell Query: db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$memberinfo"},
>   {$match:{"memberinfo.status":"approved"}}])

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$memberinfo"}, {$match:{"memberinfo.status":"approved"}}])

{
        "_id" : "123",
        "memberinfo" : {
                "height" : 170,
                "weight" : 55,
                "status" : "approved",
                "fruits" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "apple",
                                "reason" : null
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "orange",
                                "reason" : null
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "berry",
                                "reason" : null
                        }
                ]
        }
}
{
        "_id" : "456",
        "memberinfo" : {
                "height" : 160,
                "weight" : 90,
                "status" : "approved",
                "fruits" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "berry",
                                "reason" : null
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "orange",
                                "reason" : null
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Hope it Helps!

References:

https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/aggregation/

http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c

Comment: how can the `aggregrate` , `$unwind` and `$match` do in asp.net using ImongoQuery ?

Comment: because i using Imongoquery for whole web application, i cant follow the code that u suggested, sorry but thanks

Comment: I have given the Mongo Shell query, i'm not familiar with asp.net, please convert the shell query into your technology. This post has some good examples http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c

Comment: I also new in mongodb i have no idea how to convert

Comment: I have added few references which can give you some idea in using the aggregation in C#. I hope by referring these posts you should be able to convert the shell query into your required format.

Comment: As far as I can tell to do aggregation queries in .NET you need to construct the `BsonDocument` as shown in that post (the mikaelkoskinen one). It is annoyingly fiddly but I've not found anything in the standard c# drivers that will do this for you. :( In terms of testing you can use `.ToString()` on the `BsonDocument` and then compare it to the query document that Clement has provided to make sure you are constructing it correctly.

Comment: @ClementAmarnath There is no need to use aggregation, this can be done with a straightforward `find()` query with projection.

Comment: @VinceBowdren - Thanks, I have modified my description and upvoted your answer